Automated script (bash?) to download file from remote sFTP server
I am trying to write an automated script to be called as a cron Job to automatically download a couple of files from a remote sFTP server.
I have tried a few options I have found online, but all seem to error.
The machine is an Ubuntu 22.04 server.
From terminal I can connect and download the file as follows;
sftp <USER>@<HOST SERVER>

This responds;
<USER>@<HOST SERVER>'s password:

After entering the password I get an sftp prompt.
Next, I set the local download path;
sftp> lcd /var/www/local_folder

Then I can download the file/s using;
get FILE.ZIP

Then disconnect;
sftp> bye

So, its a simple process but I have been searching for a way to do this using sftp or scp in a bash script. There is a second file in /FOLDER on the remote machine, so the closest I have found is;
#!/usr/bin/expect
export PASSD="password"
expect -c 'spawn sftp <USER>@<HOST SERVER>; 
expect "*password: ";
send "$env(PASSD) \r";
expect "sftp>";
send "lcd lcd /var/www/local_folder \r";
expect "sftp>";
send "get FILE.ZIP \r";
expect "sftp>";
send "CD FOLDER \r";
expect "sftp>";
send "get FILE2.ZIP \r";
expect "sftp>";
send "bye \r"'
done

When this runs I get the following errors;
sftp_download.sh: line 3: expect: command not found
sftp_download.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
sftp_download.sh: line 15: `done'

I am not a script guru and have compiled the above by searching on the internet, can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

I just read my own question and realised that I need to install "expect", so I have installed this and now get an error saying the password is incorrect, so I have deleted line 1 (export PASSD="password") and amended line 4 (send "$env(PASSD) \r";) to "send "password \r";" But this still says the password is incorrect, even though I know it is correct because it works when I log in from terminal - any ideas?

OK, in case anyone else finds this... the password error was caused because I used;
send "password \r";

This sent the password as "password " - because there is a space between the password and the return character - when I updated with;
send "password\r";

it fixed the problem ;-)
Hopefully this will help someone.
